# Ubuntu server 16.04 - Setup static IP on independent network switch (No Internet Network switch)

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, static-ip, systemd-networkd

Please consider this.

**Scenario:**

The Device I'm using has Ubuntu server 16.04 installed. It is connected to a NETGEAR network switch but it has no internet access.

[image]

**Tried:**

Case 1) In the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

iface eth0:0 inet dhcp
```

Case 2) Tried the same configuration with `allow-hotplug eth0` instead of `auto eth0`

Case 3) Tried changing the `managed=False` to `managed=True` and vice-versa in both cases 1&2

**Issue:**

The device is **not obtaining the static IP** when it is connected to an independent switch.

Comment: I use a similar NETGEAR switch. I simply connect an RJ45 from the internet router to any port on the switch and any devices connected to the switch have internet access. For static IP i log in to the router (usually 192.168.1.1 and set it there.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my choice of words was not clear. But the constraint is that "The network is completely independant. It cannot be connected to a router or something which can manage the network". Or to put it simply, let's assume the case of when the ethernet port is not connected to anything. Will it get the static ip by default? Is it the default behaviour?